# How to offset one end of a bond in Chemfig

Tags: chemfig, tabu

I'm trying to draw hydrogen bonding between two molecules, however, the dotted line is intersecting with the charges on the oxygen. I was wondering if there was a way to offset the hydrogen bond while keeping the formatting (tabu and scalebox) the same?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ghsystem=false]{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules = all}
    \chemsetup[orbital]{overlay}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=1pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=5.5pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
\makeatother

\title{d}
\author{Generic Account}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\tabulinesep = ^ 20mm _ 20mm % border gap
\begin{tabu} to 10.5cm {|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \scalebox{1.25}{
    \chemfig{H-[:30]\charge{145=\:,35=\:}{O}(-[:-30]H)-[:30,1.25,,,dots]H-[:30]\charge{150=\:,30=\:}{O}-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]}
    }
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I recommend to not use `tabu`. It is known to cause some unwanted side effects and is unmaintained. (See also: github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu). There are definitely better alternatives with which you can get a similar output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: How about this?
[image]
This was obtained by adding the single line with the comment `%% <--` to your example file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ghsystem=false]{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules = all}
    \chemsetup[orbital]{overlay}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=1pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=5.5pt,
    dots/.style={
        shorten <=5pt,     %% <-- this line does the trick
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
\makeatother

\title{d}
\author{Generic Account}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep = ^ 20mm _ 20mm % border gap
\begin{tabu} to 10.5cm {|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \scalebox{1.25}{
    \chemfig{H-[:30]\charge{145=\:,35=\:}{O}(-[:-30]H)-[:30,1.25,,,dots]H-[:30]\charge{150=\:,30=\:}{O}-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]}
    }
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Below was my original approximate solution:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ghsystem=false]{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules = all}
    \chemsetup[orbital]{overlay}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=1pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=5.5pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
%\tabulinesep = ^ 20mm _ 20mm 
%\begin{tabu} to 10.5cm {|X[cm]|}
%    \hline
%\scalebox{1.25}{
  \chemfig{
    H
    -[:30]\charge{145=\:,35=\:}{O}(-[:-30]H)
    -#(7pt)[:30,1.25,,,dots]H     % <-- #(7pt) adjusts the departure bond sep.
    -[:30]\charge{150=\:,30=\:}{O}
    -[:-30]
    -[:30]
    -[:-30]
  }
%
%    \\
%    \hline
%\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I had to comment out several lines of your code that break the `#(7pt)` parameter for the "departure bound sep".

Comment: Thanks, the %% was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @GenericAccount, you are welcome.